# Spring Data Rest supporting json and xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-data-rest

Is it possible to have spring data rest repositories supporting both json and xml at the same time? 
I was hoping that something like that would work (but it doesn't unfortunately):

```
@RequestMapping(produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
@RepositoryRestResource
```

Comment: This seems like really bad design. You should implement 2 API endpoints, one for XML and one for JSON.

Comment: @RobinJonsson why is that bad design?

Comment: I don't think it is bad design to have one endpoint supporting multiple application types, on the contrary :). I was hoping I could support both types like we can do with normal controllers: @RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1", produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })

Comment: have a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438450/use-spring-data-rest-to-return-response-as-xml-instead-of-json

Comment: IMO it's bad design because it's very unclear what format the user can expect his response to come in. Most RESTful API's have the suffix .json etc to specifiy what type of response it's supposed to yield. If you want complexity you could still do a single endpoint with different requestmappings. (@RequestMapping supports and array of `value`)

Comment: Thanks @Jaiwo99. I believe that is the only way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: @RobinJonsson it's not bad design, it's the best design that's intended to be. Even since the term REST first introduced. .json .xml endings are really bad designs.

Comment: @EralpB I only mentioned the suffixes as examples of how to distinguish the api endpoints. Not that its good design. What i really ment was the split to specifying 2 rest endpoint methods that returns different content-types. Having one that does both is still bad design.

Comment: It's called content negotiation, and it is a good design practice.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to configure content negotiation in Spring Web MVC.

Follow this blog [post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @shazin. This is a good way to define different media types, but unfortunately it does not affect the spring data rest api's.