# Accept SOAP message in RestController using JAXB

Tags: spring, soap, jaxb

We created a Spring Boot @RestController that will accept XML request using SOAP but I could not get it to work.

Sample Message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <PostPayload xmlns="http://mynamespace/">
      <Message>
        <Header type="Main" version="1.0" desc="Some header description...">
          <Title content="The quick brown fox." />
        </Header>
        <Content />
        <Footer type="Copyright" name="Footer01">Some random content...</Footer>
      </Message>
    </PostPayload>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("rest-service")
public class MessageController {

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public String handler(@RequestBody Message message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n");

        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Message.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(message, System.out);
        } catch(JAXBException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

        return "Done!";
    }

}
```

Message Class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message")
public class Message {
   @XmlElement(name = "Header", required = true)
   private Header header;

   @XmlElement(name = "Content", required = true)
   private Content content;

   @XmlElement(name = "Footer", required = true)
   private Footer footer;

   // Getters and setters here...

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      // In here, I outputted the values of the header and footer.
   }
}
```

Header Class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Header")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Header {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type", required = true)
    private String type;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "version", required = true)
    private String version;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "desc", required = true)
    private String description;

    // Getters and setters here...
}
```

Content Class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Content")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Content {
}
```

Footer Class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Footer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Footer {
    @XmlValue
    private String value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String type;

    //Getter and setters here...
}
```

So if I send that soap message to my rest service, it is returning null. The marshaller in the rest controller is just to check if the output is the same with the request, that means that I'm reading the XML properly. Unfortunately, it is returning null. Any thoughts why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to serialize request with Jaxb because spring rest controller doing it automatically. Your **Message** class which is parameter in function must be include PostPayload and has name space (http://mynamespace/) as in xml.
restcontroller checking content-type in header and make conversion automatically.

This post include more information: [Spring Boot REST with XML Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654291/spring-boot-rest-with-xml-support)

Working example:

```
package com.mkysoft.restxml.contoller;

import com.mkysoft.restxml.domain.*;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("rest-service")
public class MessageController {

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public String handler(@RequestBody Envelope envelope) {
        System.out.println(envelope);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n");

        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Envelope.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(envelope, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

        return "Done!";
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public Envelope gethandler() {
        final Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
        final Message message = new Message();
        final Header header = new Header();
        header.setType("type");
        header.setDescription("description");
        header.setVersion("version");
        message.setHeader(header);
        message.setContent(new Content());
        message.setFooter(new Footer());
        final Body body = new Body();
        final PostPayload postPayload = new PostPayload();
        postPayload.setMessage(message);
        //body.setPostPayload(postPayload);
        envelope.setBody(body);
        return envelope;
    }

}
```

Envelope.java

```
package com.mkysoft.restxml.domain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Envelope", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
public class Envelope {

    @XmlElement(name = "Body", required = true, namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    private Body body;

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

Body.java

```
package com.mkysoft.restxml.domain;

import com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.annotation.XmlNamespace;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.xml.XMLName;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Body", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
public class Body {

    @XmlElement(name = "PostPayload", required = true, namespace = "http://mynamespace/")
    private PostPayload postPayload;

    public PostPayload getPostPayload() {
        return postPayload;
    }

    public void setPostPayload(PostPayload postPayload) {
        this.postPayload = postPayload;
    }
}
```

PostPayload.java

```
package com.mkysoft.restxml.domain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "PostPayload", namespace = "http://mynamespace/")
public class PostPayload {

    @XmlElement(name = "Message", required = true, namespace = "http://mynamespace/")
    private Message message;

    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Message.java

```
package com.mkysoft.restxml.domain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message", namespace = "http://mynamespace/")
public class Message {
    @XmlElement(name = "Header", required = true, namespace = "http://mynamespace/")
    private Header header;

    @XmlElement(name = "Content", required = true, namespace = "http://mynamespace/")
    private Content content;

    @XmlElement(name = "Footer", required = true, namespace = "http://mynamespace/")
    private Footer footer;

    public Header getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(Header header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public Content getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(Content content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Footer getFooter() {
        return footer;
    }

    public void setFooter(Footer footer) {
        this.footer = footer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // In here, I outputted the values of the header and footer.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Header.java

```
package com.mkysoft.restxml.domain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Header", namespace = "http://mynamespace/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Header {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type", required = true)
    private String type;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "version", required = true)
    private String version;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "desc", required = true)
    private String description;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Footer.java

```
package com.mkysoft.restxml.domain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Footer", namespace = "http://mynamespace/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Footer {
    @XmlValue
    private String value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String type;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Content.java

```
package com.mkysoft.restxml.domain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Content", namespace = "http://mynamespace/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Content {
}
```

Comment: Thanks mkysoft. I am aware of that Spring uses JAXB by default and the reason for the marshaller in my RestController is just to check if it reading the XML properly, however, it is just returning null. I have updated the post to reflect the Message class and subclasses.

Comment: You class hasn't got namespace property and PostPayload must be root.

Comment: Thank you mkysoft! appreciate the help. It works now when put the proper object mapping and namespace. Just one last thing, I notice that it is not getting the value of the footer text that says "Some random content..." even if I put @XmlValue.

Comment: You need namespace for all class, I updated my answer.

Comment: I added the namespace for all my classes as defined in your answer, however, I am still not getting the footer text though. This is the output I am getting from marshaller.marshal(envelope, System.out);:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Envelope xmlns="http://mynamespace/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ns2:Body>
        <PostPayload>
            <Message>
                <Header type="Main" version="1.0"/>
                <Footer name="Footer01" type="Copyright"/>
            </Message>
        </PostPayload>
    </ns2:Body>
</ns2:Envelope>

Comment: I created a separate entry for this under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798297/jaxb-xmlvalue-not-able-to-get-the-text-not-generating-empty-xml-element-and-n?noredirect=1#comment90555601_51798297